# Doubt when calculating the gravity force excerted by a planet to an object on its surface

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, planets

I have been thinking about why when you want to calculate the gravity force/acceleration that a planet exert on a obect, it is considered that all the planet's mass contributes to create a vertical force downwards.

Only the the mass below the object (those in the planet diameter where the object is locate) generate a fully vertical gravitation force. The other ones act in a diagonal line. Why is this not taken into account? Having this into account the "vertical" gravity acceleration should be less than the obtained from $g=\frac{Gm}{R^2}$.

I have tried to explain my point graphically here:

[image]

Where the brown line is the gravity force created on the person by the brown point. Only the green contribution should be taken into account to calculate the total vertical gravity exerted on the person. The red component would be compensated by a symmetrical point to the brown one.

I would like to know why/where I am wrong. I understand this point to be neglected where the distance between the object and the planet is high, because the angles would be really small, but not here, where the object is in the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I think one has to "do the math" to get a rigorous answer, but here's my take on an intuitive approach. Your brown point has a corresponding point on the other side - let's call these A and A' - and they together produce a net vertical pull downward. Because of their location, only a small part of each force is in the downward direction. Now consider two other points, B and B', directly below A and A' and near the bottom of the sphere. They also produce a net vertical pull downward and more of their force is  vertical compared to A and A'. But the effect of that is reduced by the fact that they are further away from the person. If it's an exact compensation, one can conclude that any pair of points, A and A' or B and B' etc., are contributing equally to the net downward force on the person and therefore that net downward force depends on the total mass of the planet.

Comment: Thanks, this have given me a different intuitive approach that was what I was looking for. I can't upvote answers because of reputation but thanks you anyway. As you said, I would like to check the underneath maths. I learnt a little bit of differential/integral calculus a time a go so I can try. There is online any friendlier resource than the wikipedia article about the shell theorem?

Comment: You can try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qZ_3B2F9Qk   In parts 1 and 2 he motivates the calculation and in parts 3 and 4 he goes through it step by step. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the content of the **shell theorem** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) which basically states that if you are at a radial distance $r_0$ you should only take into account the mass contained within a shell of radius $r_0$, so all the mass for $r \leq r_0$.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to take a look to the maths.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a diameter passing through the centre of the sphere and the position of the man. For the point you considered, there is an opposite point, mirrored about the diameter, that will exert a force at the same angle. So, the horizontal components of the force will be canceled out and only the vertical components will be left. This is true for any point you care to consider, there will be an opposite point to cancel the horizontal component, because this is a uniform sphere.

In general, for any body, the net gravitational force, i.e. the resultant of the forces of all the particles is directed towards the centre of mass of the body.

Comment: I understand that all the horizontal components are cancelled and  that the resultant direction is downwards. But I can't understand how the vertical component isn't smaller than it should be when you are "near" the planet. If you are far, all the gravity force the planet is applying on you pulls you downwards. But if you are near there are "a lot" of horizontal components that are being cancelled between themselves that do NOT contribute to the vertical component.

Comment: I don't understand how it can be the same situation in both cases, when you are near the vertical force value should be decreased by a certain factor from the theoreticall one.

Comment: The overall magnitude of the gravitational force also decreases when you go farther away because it is inversely proportional to the distance. Also, the theoretical value has been calculated taking everything into consideration, including the cancellation of the forces.

Answer (score 0):

Newton invented integral calculus to prove that a spherical mass can be treated as a point mass to calculate gravitational force at a point outside the sphere.  The solution takes into account everything you seem to be worried about.

The calculation is relatively easy if you know calculus, and very difficult if you don't.  If nothing else, it shows that simple logic is not a good way to come up with the answer.

OK, if you want to just use logic, I will give you my take on why I think the correct solution is also the logical solution.

You evidently agree that all horizontal forces on the person cancel.  Therefore the only net gravitational force on the person is down (the way you have drawn it.)  This gravitational force in the down direction is provided by the entire mass of the sphere.

To me it is logical to assume that if the entire mass of the sphere contributes to pulling the object in one direction, the angles really don't matter as long as everything is symmetrical the way it is with a sphere.

Comment: There is no logical approach to understand it?